# SSIS Package deployed - Fails when executed from schedule

Tags: ssis

I've deployed a SSIS package to my SQL server.
I can run the package fine by connecting to Integration Services in SSMS and right clicking on it and choosing "Run Package"

However, if I schedule the package, it fails.
It tells me to check the logs for information on why, but there is nothing in there...

Any ideas?

(this is my first SSIS package by the way)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would guess your package is doing something the SQl Server agent deosn't have the rights to do. Often it turns out that the location of file to be imported or the location where the file exported are in directories that are not open to the account that runs the SQL Server Agent.

I also agree woth Raj who said you really need to implement logging. You can;t expect to know why something fails six months down the road if you aren't recording the details of waht is happening with the package. SSIS pacakages can be hard to debug anyway, so you need those logs to know where to start looking.

Comment: I followed this - http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sqlintegrationservices/thread/40d7b04b-f7e6-49f1-83bb-7b72d8453ab6 - "saved a copy" and it seemed to work... this can't be a long term solution though?

Answer (score 1):

You have to implement logging to get the details of the error.

In SQL Server Agent, create a new job, configure it to execute the package and under the logging tab, start logging.

Then run the package and you can read the log in the job history.

Answer (score 0):

When you said you have scheduled a job, I assume you used SQL agent. In that case you can right click job and click View History and you can see the error related to job not to the package. For detail error you need to configure logging.