# DOS copy command does not work from DOS but copy works from Windows Explorer

Tags: batch-file, ssis, dos

copy,xcopy,robocopy command in dos does not work when copying a file from a sharepoint location to my local drive .  This copy of files from sharepoint location to location drive works from Windows Explorer. It seems Windows 7 and DOS are not talking . Mapped the Sharepoint folder and it still did not work from DOS .

Any ideas why this does not work ? This copy command works on other people's PCs.

Windows user has full permissions on the sharepoint site as well .

Comment: Do you run these commands with admin privileges? If yes this is "expected" behaviour

Comment: possible duplicate of [SSIS Package deployed - Fails when executed from schedule](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2479786/ssis-package-deployed-fails-when-executed-from-schedule)

Comment: What happens when the copy command is issued? Is there an error or does it silently fail? Assuming it returns and error, please provide the error message.

Answer (score 1):

Try to run as an administrator. If you are not an admin, it most likely won't allow you to copy in cmd.